# Get GameObject from array with specific name with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I wrote some code with foreach loop but it looks very ugly and I wanna translate it into LINQ version but i can't figure out how to do that
(sorry, I am new to LINQ) and can someone tell me the LINQ way of my code which is given below?

```
        GameObject[] everything = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(
                                 typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[];
        GameObject layoutContainer = new GameObject();

        foreach (GameObject obj in everything) {
            if(obj.name == "LayoutContainer") {
                layoutContainer = obj;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You looking for `FirstOrDefault` method. Something like `layoutContainer = everything.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.name == "LayoutContainer")`

Comment: Thanks for your response, it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert this to LINQ with the following code:

```
GameObject layoutContainer = everything.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.name == "LayoutContainer") ?? new GameObject();
```

This grabs the first object with the `name` of "LayoutContainer". If there is no object with that name, it will assign it a new object. This is the same functionality that you have shown in your code example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have already tried this but in FirstOrDefault method i was using { } this action qurly braces and compiler was saying that "not all code path returns a value", now i understand, i just had to pass logic as parameter and not as an action

Comment: Your error came from the scoping curly braces. Leave those out and use the code as I wrote it and you should be all set.

Comment: Yes, I did that and now all is fine

Answer (score 2):

```
GameObject layoutContainer = (from game in everything
                                          where game.name == "LayoutContainer"
                                          select game).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GameObject layoutContainer = (Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[])?
   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "LayoutContainer") ?? new GameObject();
```